# Integrating react-native into existing App

Tags: android, react-native

we are trying to integrate react-native into our existing android application:
The SDK requirements of our build.gradle are:

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 23
```

We use an Intent to call the initial React index.js:

```
Intent inte = new Intent(this, ReactNativeStarter.class);
startActivity(inte);
```

The rest of the code is from the react integrating tutorial.

When we try to call our react component we get the following error:

```
12-16 09:37:52.041 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
Process: XXXXX, PID: XXXX
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libfbjni.so" needed by "libreactnativejni.so"; caused by cannot locate symbol "_ZSt16__get_once_mutexv" referenced by "libfbjni.so"...
    at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:331)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:982)
    at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibrary(DirectorySoSource.java:63)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:209)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:178)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutor.<clinit>(JSCJavaScriptExecutor.java:25)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutor$Factory.create(JSCJavaScriptExecutor.java:20)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:183)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:169)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Can you help?

Comment: the issue is solved by changing the exclude to pickFirst in the packagingOptions. ater that we have a new react-native error:

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' 
     (declaration of 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' appears in /data/data/at.??????/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.facebook.react-react-native-0.20.1_3762d580ab3ced1fa2f7503493d38e666994b9fa-classes.dex)

Comment: did you solve that error?

Comment: Hello
yes. The Issue was solved by adding pickFirst instad of Exclude for the library

Comment: can u please post that code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is solved by changing the Exclude to pickFirst in the build.gradle

Comment: Could you be more explicit with some a build.gradle example ?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11485#issuecomment-267917738